# how can invoke install Applications by c# code?

Tags: c#

how can invoke install Applications by c# code?
I want to install an application as winrar.exe by C# code

Comment: you want to install a C# application?

Comment: Please give more details. It's impossible to answer this question at the moment - which means it's likely to be closed pretty quickly.

Comment: Specifically, do you want to install an application *written* in C#? Or do you want to write an installer application *using* C#?

Comment: I want to install an application as winrar.exe by C# code

Comment: I think what you mean is: 'Using C#, how can I programmatically install another program?'. So like, a program that runs installers automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exe file can be invoked through c#.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("exe file location");
```

The above line on execution  will start the exe file(could be a setup file).

Answer (score 1):

Create a setup project:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx

Comment: Note that I meant this if you wish you install your own code that you have created. If you wish to control another compiled installer you will need another technique such as SendKeys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx

Comment: I am sorry about misapprehension.... I want to install an application as winrar.exe by C# code

Comment: `SendKeys` to install an application? Wow, I'd be a little afraid to install one of your apps on my machine.

Comment: I was advocating the use of Process control to send keys to an external installer of which you wished to install automatically. Much like the answer above, except with the ability to click NEXT programmatically.